# SSLStream fails decryption exception

Tags: c#, ssl

I'm attempting to program a secure websocket server in C#. I'm using a self-signed certificate. I'm getting an exception message when reading from the SSLStream saying "The decryption operation failed".  What's wrong with my code?

My code:

```
string ip = "156.96.119.19";
            int port = 8960;
            var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("WebSocket - Server has started on {0}:{1}, Waiting for a connection…", ip, port);


            var certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\mypfx.pfx", "1234", X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();      
                Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");
                SslStream stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);                
                stream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, false, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12, true);
                Console.WriteLine("server authenticated:  " + stream.IsAuthenticated);
                while (true)
                {
                    int i = stream.ReadByte();  // <<<-- Exception is thrown right here.
                    if (i == -1) break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("end of stream reached");
            }
```

The client:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <body>
    Testing Websockets
    
    <br><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.writeln("creating websocket...");
        var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://156.96.119.19:8960");
        websocket.onopen = (e) => {
            document.writeln("testing");
            websocket.send(message);
        };
    </script>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Is the self-signed server certificate imported as trusted into the client? Does it match the URL? Check the console in your client for errors. Apart from that (i.e. a problem which will occur once you've fixed the current one) - a secure websocket (wss) is not the same as a TCP socket with TLS on top. You actually need to implement the websocket application protocol in your server - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455

Comment: Post the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. That contains any inner exceptions that may be telling you why this failed. Perhaps the certificate is invalid or expired? Self-signed certificates are only valid on the machine that created them

Comment: The ReadByte() method will give an exception only if the connection is closed.  Add an exception handles and see what the exception says.

Comment: There are all manner of side issues with your code: the listener should not use a hard-coded local IP address. The `client` needs to be disposed, as do the streams. `stream.ReadByte` is a poor way to read a stream, instead use `Read` and check if 0 bytes are returned. What you are doing is not following the websocket protocol anyway. Why reinvent the wheel? `HttpListener` can do websockets, why not just use that?